# How to make d3 div tooltip scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nvvX02aRMbyqaKmvPEdw?p=preview

```
div.tooltip {   
position: absolute;         
text-align: center;         
width: 100px;                   
height: 100px;                  
padding: 2px;               
font: 12px sans-serif;      
background: lightsteelblue; 
border: 0px;        
border-radius: 8px;         
pointer-events: none;       
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

When you hover over a circle, a long tooltip with a vertical scrollbar shows up.  However, I can't scroll the tooltip.  The div doesn't respond to any user actions.  How can I make the div respond to the scroll event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems to me you have effectively disabled scrolling with `pointer-events: none` in your css class.

As soon as this property is removed (in your plunker) the div becomes scrollable.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!